# Google Maps v3 get Place Name/Address from coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have found addresses and latlng from searching a placename using `google.maps.placesAutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions`.

How do/can you get closest placenames/addresses with latlng coordinates?

P.S. using javascript

Comment: How about adding a helpful comment rather than down voting my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16505977/265167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how you get  LatLng's as result from  `getPlacePredictions` (AFAIK this doesn't return a LatLng).

But however, when you have the LatLng's, use [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to calculate the distance and select the result with the shortest distance